# What determines the Earth's atmospheric transmission window?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, atmospheric-science, plasma-physics

That is, the opacity/transparency spectrum for electromagnetic radiation.The ionosphere plays a big part but is that due to the composition of ionospheric plasma(not to mention the plasma frequency)? Part of the point of asking this question is the possibility that on different planets that have atmospheres, the transmission/opacity spectrum for the RF band(including the microwave bands) may be different. If so, this might be of particular relevance to SETI.